# Failed to bind twitter bootstrap typeahead for JQuery Generated rows with text fields

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a table with a single row, the rows has a text field in its first cell and the text field in bind to twitter bootstrap typeahead in a separate js file. But users can create rows using the add button and the first row is cloned to create additional rows. Now I expected the typeahead to work just fine in these cloned text fields but it doesn't and no error is displayed in the console. The cloned text fields have the same id and name to the original text field. Any idea why this might be? and any suggestions on how to handle it?

Comment: I have found this library https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery/downloads but I really would appreciate it if I could solve this with out adding yet another library in my project

Comment: Can you share some of the code? How are the cloned rows getting created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that **.typeahead()** is not being initiated on the dynamically created/cloned rows. You can trigger an event when the row is added and attach the typeahead using jquery .on()...

```
$('#btnAddRow').click(function(){
    var newRow = $('<div class="row"><input type="text" placeholder="Start typing.." class="typeahead" data-items="3"></div>');
    newRow.insertBefore('#addRow');
    $('.typeahead').trigger('added');

});

$('.typeahead').on('added',function(){
    $('.typeahead').typeahead(typeaheadSettings);
});
```

[**Here's a working example**](http://bootply.com/61431)