# Selecting the row with the twitter type ahead and updating values in the same row

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have  a table of text field which is bind to twitter type ahead like this.

[Failed to bind twitter bootstrap typeahead for JQuery Generated rows with text fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563049/failed-to-bind-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-for-jquery-generated-rows-with-text-f)

I want the result of the selection from the type ahead to be displayed in the next text fields in the same row(nth row). But only the first row is updated so I tried this.

```
$('#myTable').find('tr').click( function(){
   $(this).find('#mytext1').val(val1);
   $(this).find('#mytext2').val(val2);
}
```

But this needs additional click after the selection is made and duplicates result of the last row selected. So can anyone help and suggest how to handle this situation?

Changed the code like this

```
$('#mytext0').live('change', function(){
       //ajax call based on the user selection of mytext0, which is twitter bootstrap bind
       $(this).closest('tr').find('#mytext1').val(val1);
       $(this).closest('tr').find('#mytext2').val(val2);
});
```

But this is not working as closest doesn't know the method find.
Any ideas??

Comment: $(this).closest('tr').find('#mytext1').andSelf().filter('#mytext1').val(val1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out using a blog by tatiyants @ 
http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-json-objects-with-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/ and then in updater i called this method to update the other fields in the table based on the user selection
here goes the method:

```
function getDetail(id) { 
   var $selected; 
   $('#mytext0').live("change keyup", function (){
     $selected = $(this).closest("tr");
   });
   $.ajax({
     //make a post based on the id to your server and upon success
     success: function(result){
         $selected.find('#mytext1').andSelf().filter('#mytext1').val(result);
         $selected.find('#mytext2').andSelf().filter('#mytext2').val(result);
      }         
   })
}
```

This has solved the fact that the result was only updating the first row.